# Stop Threads created with ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem that have a specific task

Tags: c#, multithreading, abort

Let's say I queue those two methods in a `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Output");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    });
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Output2");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    });
}
```

Is there a way to stop all the threads that output `Console.WriteLine("Output2");` but keep the ones running that output `Console.WriteLine("Output");` ?

Comment: I am not really able to completely understand your requirement. You can just don't start that particular task based on some condition. As you must be needing some condition to decide.

Comment: By the way this is method (not thread) that is executed by the available thread in the ThreadPool.

Comment: What version of C# are you using?  Is it 4.0+?  If so, you should ideally be using `Task` objects instead, and it would help greatly at addressing this problem.

Comment: do you have a resource where I could read about putting like 2k tasks into a pool and then having only 50 tasks run at a time till all tasks are complete like the threadpool?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use a CancellationToken:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Output");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    });
}

CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s =>
    {
        CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken) s;
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;
        Console.WriteLine("Output2");
        token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(1000);
    }, cts.Token);
}

cts.Cancel();
```

Comment: This assumes the OP is on .NET 4.0+, which he may not be (given that he's using the thread pool directly and not tasks).  If he is, then this is the way to go.

Comment: If using < 4.0, the cancellation token could be replaced with a ManualResetEvent.

Comment: @jaket - (if I understand correctly) ManualResetEvent is for a different situation than CancellationToken. It is used for controlling when a thread STARTS executing. It CAN help with threads that have not yet begun. But it does not help STOP threads  that have already begun executing. For that, before .Net 4.0, programmer must write their own code, like [Lirik's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13590411/199364).

Comment: I just realized Lirik's answer has the same limitation. I see that the question was worded ambiguously. See my comment there for how to adapt the code for stopping a long-running task, before .Net 4.0.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve. ManualResetEvent can be used for many purposes beyond starting a thread. In the example above the token.IsCancellationPending could be replaced with mre.WaitOne(0) and the token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(1000) with mre.WaitOne(1000).  There is nothing to STOP a thread short of an Abort (which is a horrible idea) other than polling *something* - like the bool in Links answer, a MRE which is like a waitable bool or a CancellationToken which is more robust and designed specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that. If you want to do something a long the lines then you must write some code to manage it. At the very basic level you need something like this:

```
object syncObject = new object();
bool shouldOutput2 = true;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s =>
{
    lock(syncObject)
    {
        if(!shouldOutput2)
        {
           return;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Output2");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
});
```

Once you queue the items, then you can set the flag in order to tell the remaining items not to execute:

```
   lock(syncObject)
   {
        shouldOutput2 = false;
   }
```

This is a very dirty way of doing it, but it seems like the only way given your example. If you can tell us more about what is the actual real-world behavior you're trying to accomplish, then there could be some better options.

Comment: The placement of your lock takes the 100 items previously executed in parallel and runs them serially.  The lock should only cover the `if`.

Comment: @Servy ah, yes! Thanks for that catch, I've moved the execution outside the lock+check.

Comment: Using a `CancellationToken` is much cleaner, as it takes care of the synchronization issues for you, but since it's plausible the OP doesn't have .NET 4.0 it's beneficial to have this here.

Comment: This answer, as written, only helps if the queued object has not yet started running. To stop a long-running operation containing a loop, place the test inside the loop. `while (..) { if (!shouldContinue) return;  ... }`